# How do I search for a coordinate in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, latitude-longitude

I have a very simple longitude and latitude I need to locate on the map and cannot find this for the life of me, sorry for the dumb question.  So basically I need to find 36.336429, -119.314682 on the map, I don't need a pin or anything special, I just need QGIS to point me to it.

Comment: paste it in the coordinates box at the bottom of QGIS and ensure the EPSG is 4326

Comment: @DPSSpatial_BoycottingGISSE Then after I do this I have to switch *back* to EPSG:3857 in order to see the map properly (e.g. not looking like a "bird's eye" view due to the projection change).  Seems like a lot of work.

Answer (score 15):

You can use the coordinate window in the status bar to pan the map to this location. Enter your coordinate in a `lon, lat` format (note that it's the reverse order of how you wrote it here), and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Just make sure your mouse cursor doesn't stray into the map window, or it will reset the coordinate you've typed in.

[image]

Answer (score 12):

You have 2 options (well, it is QGIS, so maybe more)

--> use the coordinate window in the status bar

--> install the super-simple plugin "Zoom to Point"

Comment: Thanks very much.  However when I paste in 36.337296, -119.292410 to both the plugin and at the bottom of the screen it takes me to the ocean.  My "Coordinate" at the bottom doesn't match what Google says.  Any help appreciated, assuming it's a plane or project thing or something? I don't know how to fix that though to match "real GPS"

Comment: Usually coordinate represent X / Y, as -119.2924 can't be the y-coordinate (range 0 to 90, 0 to -90 only), it has to be the X coordinate. "Zoom to point" jumps me somewhere south-east of Fresno.

Comment: This plugin isn't listed in v3.18

Answer (score 2):

QGIS has a plug in called Lat Lon Tools which you can use to zoom to coordinates, click-copy coordinates, among other functions. Easy to use.[image]