# Searching by coordinates with some crosshair in the center in QGIS

Tags: qgis, coordinates

I know how to search by coordinates in QGIS from this query:

[How do I search for a coordinate in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/238005/how-do-i-search-for-a-coordinate-in-qgis/238032)

but when I type the coordinates of my potential place is quite hard to define it roughly, because nothing shows the certain point on which the coordinates were defined.

[image]

I can play by changing the scale, which is next to, but I would like to have some crosshair in the middle of the screen, which will clearly mark the place with coordinates provided manually. Is it possible in QGIS?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use [Lat Lon Tools](https://github.com/NationalSecurityAgency/qgis-latlontools-plugin) Plugin.

After installing plugin:
(1) Click on "Zoom to Coordinate" button  on the "Lat Lon Tools Toolbar"
(2) Open "Lat Lon Settings"
(3) Select "Project CRS"
(4) Enter the coordinates, press Enter

The plugin adds a crosshair. It remains until closing the "Zoom to Coordinate" window.

[image]

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for! Now I have the crosshair and it stays in the same place even when I drag the map. Thank you very much!